# Demonstrating string comparison with Java

Tags: java, string, comparison, equals

I want to demonstrate with a few line of code that in Java, that to compare two strings (`String`), you have to use `equals()` instead of the operator `==`.

Here is something I tried :

```
public static void main(String Args[]) {
   String s1 = "Hello";
   String s2 = "Hello";

   if (s1 == s2)
      System.out.println("same strings");
   else
      System.out.println("different strings");
}
```

I was expecting this output : `different strings`, because with the test `s1 == s2` I'm actually comparing two references (i.e. addresses) instead of the objet's content.

But I actually got this output : `same strings` !

Browsing the internet I found that some Java implementation will optimize the above code so that `s1`and `s2` *will* actually reference the same string.

Well, how can I demonstrate the problem using the `==` operator when comparing Strings (or Objects) in Java ?

Comment: Actually, per the JLS, all Java compilers should perform that optimization.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The compiler does some optimizations in your case so that `s1` and `s2` are really the same object. You can work around that by using

```
String s1 = new String( "Hello" );
String s2 = new String( "Hello" );
```

Then you have two distinct objects with the same text content.

Comment: thanks ! I didn't know that using `new` or not when instanciating a String would produce something different !

Answer (score 2):

> Well, how can I demonstrate the problem using the == operator when comparing Strings (or Objects) in Java ?

Here a way:

```
String s = "ab";
String t = new String("ab");
System.out.println(s == t); // false
```

Also be careful when comparing primitive wrappers and using auto-boxing: Integer (and Long) for instance caches (and re-uses!) the values -128..127. So:

```
Integer s = -128;
Integer t = -128;
System.out.println(s == t);
```

will print `true`, while:

```
Integer s = -129;
Integer t = -129;
System.out.println(s == t);
```

prints `false`!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about caching of values -128..127. I'm not sure to understand the reason why Java does that, but it's good to know !

Comment: @Jérôme, this is done because the developers thought (think) these values were used so often that it was beneficial to *not* create new instances of these values each time. And since they're immutable, it can't hurt to *re-use* these instances.

Comment: Its a great example of Flyweight pattern.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA maintains a String Pool in the heap space, where it tries to have multiple references for same values if possible.

Had you written :

```
   String s1 = new String ("Hello");
   String s2 = new String ("Hello");
```

it would have given you the output : "different strings".'new' keyword creates a new object reference while not giving new will first check the string pool for its existence.